# Deployment issue - can EncryptSensitivewithUSERKEY default be overridden by editing XML?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We were moving SSIS packages that run OK on my machine to a different environment

We were getting the error message Failed to decrypt protected XML node "DTS:Password" with error 0x8009000B. So we tried to change protectionlevel to 0 in all the packages through the XML editor, but we are still getting the same messages.

If we resave all the packages on my machine with DontSaveSensitive and deploy them to the other environment will we be sure to get rid of that message?

Comment: see @billinkc's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14219602/236348

Answer (score 3):

1. When you saved the package on the server, it encrypted the sensitve parts by default to your login.
2. When you changed the protection level in the xml to a 0 you didn't cause it to decrypt itself, it is still encrypted, it just no longer knows how it was encrypted.
3. Yes, if you resave the packages from source with Don't Save Sensitive, the resulting files will not be encrypted and will run properly (assuming they have no other problems) on any machine with the same release level of SSIS.
4. See billinkc's answer to another question in my comment above.  It offers a great overview of how Protection levels work in SSIS.