# Locked out of SSIS Package

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, encryption, ssis, visual-studio-2005

I tried to access one of my SSIS packages only to be presented with the error message (Text in square brackets is not literal):

> Error 1:    Error loading Package.dtsx: Failed to decrypt a package that
>     is encrypted with a user key. You may not be the user who encrypted
>     this package, or you are not using the same machine that was used to
>     save the package. [path to file].[Package].dtsx
>
> Error:  2   Error loading 'Package.dtsx' : Failed to remove package
>   protection with error 0x8009000B "Key not valid for use in specified
>   state.". This occurs in the CPackage::LoadFromXML method.[path to file].[Package].dtsx

It also prevents me entering the package completely

Screen When opening package: 
[image]

Comment: You created the package & don't *recall* changing the `PackageProtectionLevel`. You have a new computer and are unable to open the package due to the error about? You should either be prompted for a key when you open the package *or* you are using a different account. If it's the later, I would expect you to be logged in through Active Directory which would present the same account SID regardless of the machine you are currently using. [More Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209293/ssis-packages-using-package-protection-level/14219602#14219602) Ring GCHQ, see if they know the pwd ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your package was encrypted by a user.  This could have been you are you loging in to the pc with a diffrent login or from a diffrent machine?   Your not going to be able to open it until you figure out who encrypted it or from what account it was encrypted from.

Comment: I created the package but iv'e had a new work machine recently. I didn't setup encryption explicitly. Its strange because I'm not locked out of any of my other packages

Comment: if i remember corectly its just a flag you set on the package you could have clicked it with out realiseing it.

Comment: Is there any way to extract any info / recover the package (as its very large and will take a few days If I had to remake it)

Comment: I was just thinking about that.  You could try and open the file on your harddrive.  The source is basicly just a weird form of XML.  but my guess is its encrypted which means you cant edit it with out being able to decrypt it.  So i think your stuck.  Try googleing around maybe someone has a way of cracking it.

Comment: Yeah I've opened it up and the XML is scrambled. I've had a good google around but couldn't find a solution that worked