# How to edit SSIS packages with protection level set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey?

Tags: ssis, etl

I am a newbie to SSIS packages.

I have a package created by a previous DBA using an account called: adminabc. The previous DBA left and took the adminabc password along with him.

I had to document the SSIS packages so I logged into the server remotely using a different account and opened a copy of the SSIS package in Visual Studio and saw that the protection was set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey. At that time, I didn't have any need to edit or make changes to the package.

Fast forward a few months, there is now a new VP who is telling me to reset all user login passwords for SQL Sever. I am trying to explain to him that SSIS packages with protection set to "EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey" can only be edited if the same user logs back in and for that I would need the original password for adminabc to make changes in the connection properties as these packages have been set up in SQL Server Job Agent.

My problem lies with changing the connection properties in the package which requires the original adminabc account as the protection was set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey. Is there any other way to make edits to the package as I don't have the password for adminabc.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should be simply able to open any package on your machine.
The default protection level for development is the user key that is Windows account based. The packages still can change hands.

Comment: Apologies for the question not being clear. My problem lies with changing the connection properties in the package which requires the original adminabc account as the protection was set to EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey. Is there any other way to make edits to the package as I don't have the password for adminabc.

Comment: @sravee Are you sure it is actually not the EncryptSensitiveWithPassword protection level?

Answer (score 0):

The first bulleted item in the following link regarding a similar scenario for the EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey may help resolve your issue.

[SSIS Packages Using Package Protection Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14209293/ssis-packages-using-package-protection-level/14219602#14219602)

Please let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you sir! I will definitely try this.